# Iperf3 testing LTE speed

Tags: maximize, lte

i've been asked to run LTE on iperf3, the result is quite bad with low kpi,  do you know how to maximize the speed, until reach enough kpi?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give details about your configuration ? Is it an LTE dongle you're testing with ?

Comment: Im running using huawei 4G broadband, does this help?

Comment: When i try to do the speedtest, the kpi really matched the LTE speed. When i do the test, the result didn't matched the speedtest result, with low kpi.

Comment: Please post the iperf command you are using and the LTE configuration.

Comment: Where do you run the second end, I.e. the second iPerf client/server?

Answer (score 0):

Try NTTTCP-for-Linux, or netperf?

ntttcp-for-linux: https://github.com/Microsoft/ntttcp-for-linux

netperf: http://www.netperf.org/netperf/